# Name that function! (because I can't)

Tags: function, language-agnostic, naming-conventions

I'm thinking of a function for localization purposes where I know exactly what it is supposed to do, **and** how to do it, but i can't for the life of me figure out a good name for it. I'm pretty sure there is a decent standard expression in the english language that could apply brilliantly to this thing here, I just can't find it.

The question itself is totally language agnostic but the code here is in PHP because that's what I'm writing at the moment.

So please, name my function!

```
/**
 * Expand a number into a format string based on its value, giving
 * different format strings for 0, 1 and greater than one.
 * 
 * example:
 *  myFun(count($apples), 'No apples', 'one apple', '%d apples.');
 *
 * @param integer $aNumber
 * @param string $ifZero
 * @param string $ifOne
 * @param string $ifGreaterThanOne
 * @return string 
 */
function myFunc($aNumber, $ifZero, $ifOne, $ifGreaterThanOne)
{
    assert('is_integer($aNumber) && $aNumber > -1;');
    assert('is_string($ifZero);');
    assert('is_string($ifOne);');
    assert('is_string($ifGreaterThanOne);');

    $result = null;

    if ($aNumber == 0)
    {
        $result = strpos($ifZero, '%d') > -1 
                ? sprintf($ifZero, $aNumber) 
                : $ifZero;
    }
    else if ($aNumber == 1)
    {
        $result = strpos($ifOne, '%d') > -1 
                ? sprintf($ifOne, $aNumber) 
                : $ifOne;
    }
    else
    {
        $result = strpos($ifGreaterThanOne, '%d') > -1 
                ? sprintf($ifGreaterThanOne, $aNumber) 
                : $ifGreaterThanOne;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: @Dennis, I think you're more awake that I am since I have no clue what you're saying. Rest assured though, Joel and Jeff will most likely just be pleased that a programmer got to ask a programming question on their programmer support site, **and** received actually helpful comments as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most technical name I've seen is "CardinalityLabel," but I usually call it CountLabel.

Comment: that about sounds like it! cardinalize tho seems like  nicer word to me. http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cardinalize

Answer (score 1):

What does it do?  It formats things.

What does it operate on?  Numbers.

How does it distinguish numbers?  Bins.

```
binned_number_format
```

Would be my suggestion (or some combination of these three words in an order that you find most logically appealing).

Comment: i was looking more for something like ordinalize, a one word thing. I've seen it in use before, just can't think of it. <bashes-head against-wall> thanks for the try tho!

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is converting an integer to a natural language expression.
So I would go for:

```
int2natural();
```

Comment: I'd expect int2natural(2) to return 'two'

Answer (score 0):

```
humanize_item_count(...)
```

Or

```
humanize_item_quantity(...)
```